# Is adding argument validators to internal functions bad practice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend, backend

I am trying to write a class to be used in my react app. The client of this function is my app only. Do I still need to valid arguments in the constructor function, etc.?

Comment: Better idea (and something that greatly helps in non-trivial projects anyway): use TypeScript so that the validation is done during compilation (or directly in your IDE) instead of at runtime

Comment: But even with typescript there are still certain things that need to be manually validated, no. An argument can only be one of several arguments in an array?

Comment: Sure, sometimes you'll need JS as well

Comment: So you would agree that even though this class is only meant to be used by my app only, it still needs argument validation?

Comment: If it's used in so many places that you can't check through the calls individually to make sure their logic is correct, I guess you could, but making sure the logic is good would make more sense

Answer (score 1):

IMO, validators are needed, when a function caller is unknown. What are the scenarios where the caller of function is unknown?

- When the function is called by users of the application.
- When the function is called by users(other programmers) of the module that has the function.
- When the function is called the author of the function, who happen to forgot what are all the parameters that the function takes.

So,

- If I am the only person who would ever call that function **AND**
- If I am sure that I would remember the parameters or I would always
  ensure that I pass there right parameters:

  - I wouldn't write any
    validations.

If the same function happen to be used by other programmers or users, the first thing that I would do is to add validations.

When I am adding validations,

- If I am sure that the function users are programmers, then I would simply have assert statements or throw statements.
- If the users are functions are actual users, then I would have human readable error messages.